# Full Stack NextJS Application

Tags: node.js, database, next.js

I created a lot of projects with ReactJS.
Therefore i created a frontend with ReactJS and a backend with express js.
Now i want to switch to NextJS to avoid creating a seperate backend, because NextJS has api routes builded in.

So i created a new NextJS project with `npx create-next-app MyProject --ts` for typescript support.
The first steps were great because of rendering, routing etc.

But then i wanted to add a local database (mariadb) to fetch data.
In my last projects i used `typeorm` as ORM witch worked very well on the express js backend.
But i was not able to add typeorm to nextjs. And i didn't find any post which explains how to do it. The only orm which seems to work is `prisma`. But i don't like the syntax.

So i'm thinking if NextJS is the framework to choose to program applications with local db.
What is your stack to create a web application?

Answer (score 0):

I have use https://massivejs.org/ to connect my fullstack NextJS but with PostgreSQL instead.